# почему не нажимается левая кнопка мыши в режиме редактирования фортнайт

Tags: python, pyautogui

Вот код:

```py
import pyautogui, mouse, keyboard, win32api, win32con, win32gui, time

isClicking = False
button_pressed = False
def set_clicker():
    global isClicking
    if isClicking:
        isClicking = False
    else:
        isClicking = False

keyboard.add_hotkey("f7", set_clicker)


print("это макросы для фортнайта")
print("нажми f7 и ты будешь стрелять без разброса с ппшки с двойным магазином. когда возьмешь другое оружие на жми еще раз f7, а иначе с других оружий твой прицел будет лететь вниз")
print("оставь стенку на 1 удар с кирки нажми на r и ты отберешь стенку врага. ")
stenka = input("напиши на какую кнопку у тебя начинается режим строительства:")
stenka1 = input("напиши на какую кнопку у тебя стоит стенка:")


while True:
    if isClicking:
        if mouse.is_pressed("left"):
            win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 0, 1, 0, 0)
            time.sleep(0.01)
        if mouse.is_pressed("right"):
            if mouse.is_pressed("left"):
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 0, 1, 0, 0)
                time.sleep(0.03)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("r"):
        mouse.click("left")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        pyautogui.press(stenka)
        time.sleep(0.10)
        pyautogui.press(stenka1)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        mouse.click("left")
```

на последней строке не нажимается клавиша мыши и я понял что в фортнайт в режиме строительства почему-то она не нажимается. Помогите решить проблему